# Codeigniter htaccess for multiple applications

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello guys can you help me how set proper url in codeigniter using multiple applications and i proper .htaccess

## Folder Structure

```
-application
 -api
 -cms
-system
-api.php
-cms.php
```

Its works when a use this

```
http://localhost/kitkat_funs/cms.php/
http://localhost/kitkat_funs/api.php/
```

But i want this

```
http://localhost/kitkat_funs/cms/
http://localhost/kitkat_funs/api/
```

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following steps:
In config=>config.php, replace like following.

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Please put following code into your .htaccess file, this might help you to achieve the result.

## write your project folder name as rewritebase

```
RewriteBase /yourprojname/    

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*    
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

*take backup of your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appear when you working with Codeigniter using Multiple application(and multiple index_appname.php. Ofcourse you can add new line in .htaccess everytime you add another application but that is not convenience.

The solution is using basic Regular Expression. You need to write 2 section, one is for address without slash, and the other with more than one slash after index file

Note: in this case the index.php file has prefix "index_" following with app name

```
# If the user types without trailing slash example www.host.com/kitkat_funs/appname
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w*)$ index_$1\.php [L,QSA]

# If the user enter in any system section with slash example www.host.com/kitkat_funs/appname/page/etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$ index_$2\.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Everytime user enter address right after domain name, for example `www.host.com/kitkatname/cms`

.htaccess will automatically redirect to `www.host.com/kitkatname/cms.php`

now you can get rid .php extension on your index file